# async/await, Task and [weak self]

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, swift-concurrency

Okay so we all know that in traditional concurrency in Swift, if you are performing (for example) a network request inside a class, and in the completion of that request you reference a function that belongs to that class, you must pass `[weak self]` in, like this:

```
func performRequest() {
   apiClient.performRequest { [weak self] result in
      self?.handleResult(result)
   }
}
```

This is to stop us strongly capturing `self` in the closure and causing unnecessary retention/inadvertently referencing other entities that have dropped out of memory already.

How about in async/await? I'm seeing conflicting things online so I'm just going to post two examples to the community and see what you think about both:

```
class AsyncClass {
   func function1() async {
      let result = await performNetworkRequestAsync()
      self.printSomething()
   }

   func function2() {
      Task { [weak self] in
         let result = await performNetworkRequestAsync()
         self?.printSomething()         
      }
   }

   func function3() {
      apiClient.performRequest { [weak self] result in
         self?.printSomething()
      }
   }

   func printSomething() {
      print("Something")
   }
}
```

`function3` is straightforward - old fashioned concurrency means using `[weak self]`.
`function2` I think is right, because we're still capturing things in a closure so we should use `[weak self]`.
`function1` is this just handled by Swift, or should I be doing something special here?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Bottom line, there is often little point in using `[weak self]` capture lists with `Task` objects. Use cancelation patterns instead.

---

A few detailed considerations:

1. **Weak capture lists are not required.**

   You said:

   > in traditional concurrency in Swift, if you are performing (for example) a network request inside a class, and in the completion of that request you reference a function that belongs to that class, you must pass `[weak self]` …

   This is not true. Yes, it may be prudent or advisable to use the `[weak self]` capture list, but it is not required. The only time you “must” use a `weak` reference to `self` is when there is a persistent strong reference cycle.

   For well-written asynchronous patterns (where the called routine releases the closure as soon as it is done with it), there is no persistent strong reference cycle risk. The `[weak self]` is *not* required.
2. **Nonetheless, weak capture lists are useful.**

   Using `[weak self]` in these traditional escaping closure patterns still has utility. Specifically, in the absence of the `weak` reference to `self`, the closure will keep a strong reference to `self` until the asynchronous process finishes.

   A common example is when you initiate a network request to show some information in a scene. If you dismiss the scene while some asynchronous network request is in progress, there is no point in keeping the view controller in memory, waiting for a network request that merely updates the associated views that are long gone.

   Needless to say, the `weak` reference to `self` is really only part of the solution. If there’s no point in retaining `self` to wait for the result of the asynchronous call, there is often no point in having the asynchronous call continue, either. E.g., we might marry a `weak` reference to `self` with a `deinit` that cancels the pending asynchronous process.
3. **Weak capture lists are less useful in Swift concurrency.**

   Consider this permutation of your `function2`:

   ```swift
   func function2() {
       Task { [weak self] in
           let result = await apiClient.performNetworkRequestAsync()
           …
       }
   }
   ```

   This looks like it should not keep a strong reference to `self` while `performNetworkRequestAsync` is in progress. But the reference to a property, `apiClient`, will introduce a strong reference, without any warning or error message. E.g., below, I let `AsyncClass` fall out of scope at the red signpost, but despite the `[weak self]` capture list, it was not released until the asynchronous process finished:

   [image]

   The `[weak self]` capture list accomplishes very little in this case. Remember that in Swift concurrency there is a lot going on behind the scenes (e.g., code after the “suspension point” is a “continuation”, etc.). It is not the same as a simple GCD dispatch. See [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/).

   If, however, you make all property references `weak`, too, then it will work as expected:

   ```swift
   func function2() {
       Task { [weak self] in
           let result = await self?.apiClient.performNetworkRequestAsync()
           …
       }
   }
   ```

   Hopefully, future compiler versions will warn us of this hidden strong reference to `self`.
4. **Make tasks cancelable.**

   Rather than worrying about whether you should use `weak` reference to `self`, one could consider simply supporting cancelation:

   ```swift
   var task2: Task<Void, Never>?

   func function2() {
       task2?.cancel()        // you might want to cancel previous task, if any; it depends…

       task2 = Task {
           let result = await apiClient.performNetworkRequestAsync()
           …
           task2 = nil
       }
   }
   ```

   And then:

   ```swift
   override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       task2?.cancel()
       …
       super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
   }
   ```

   Obviously, that assumes that your task supports cancelation. Most of the Apple async API does. (But if you have written your own [`withUnsafeContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/3815002-withunsafecontinuation/)-style implementation, then you will want to periodically check [`Task.isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3814832-iscancelled/) or wrap your call in a [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/3814990-withtaskcancellationhandler/) or other similar mechanism to add cancelation support. But this is beyond the scope of this question.)

   Now, the details  will vary based on your specific requirements. For example, the above pattern is only keeping track of a single `Task` for each function. If you might be calling it multiple times, then you will need to figure out how you would want to handle that. Would you like to always cancel the prior one, like shown above, so that you always only have one task to keep track of? Or do you want to keep track of multiple tasks, so that you can cancel them all when the view is dismissed. It varies. And, SwiftUI often even calls for a different pattern altogether (e.g., if launching the task in [`.task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier, it would then automatically cancel when the view is dismissed). It all depends upon your specific requirements.

   But do not get lost in these details: The big-picture idea is to cancel tasks when they are no longer needed. That eliminates the concern about a task keeping a strong reference to `self` longer than needed.

Comment: "Hopefully, future compiler versions will warn us of this hidden strong reference to self." It seems that the compiler in Xcode 13.4 treats this as a warning, but it will become an error in Swift 6.

Comment: In 4. `task = nil` seems like a race condition to me if `function2` is called repeatedly, perhaps better to have `task?.cancel()` in line above `task = Task {` to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, one wants to consider clearly whether this task may may be called multiple times, and if so, how one wants to handle it. Cancel the prior one? Keep track of a collection of tasks so you can cancel multiple ones when no longer needed? A whole bunch of alternatives. I have attempted to clarify my answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

> if you are performing (for example) a network request inside a class, and in the completion of that request you reference a function that belongs to that class, you must pass [weak self] in, like this

This isn't quite true. When you create a closure in Swift, the variables that the closure references, or "closes over", are retained by default, to ensure that those objects are valid to use when the closure is called. This includes `self`, when `self` is referenced inside of the closure.

The typical retain cycle that you want to avoid requires two things:

1. The closure retains `self`, and
2. *`self` retains the closure back*

The retain cycle happens if `self` holds on to the closure strongly, and the closure holds on to `self` strongly — by default ARC rules with no further intervention, neither object can be released (because something has retained it), so the memory will never be freed.

There are two ways to break this cycle:

1. Explicitly break a link between the closure and `self` when you're done calling the closure, e.g. if `self.action` is a closure which references `self`, assign `nil` to `self.action` once it's called, e.g.

   ```swift
   self.action = { /* Strongly retaining `self`! */
       self.doSomething()

       // Explicitly break up the cycle.
       self.action = nil
   }
   ```

   This isn't usually applicable because it makes `self.action` one-shot, and you also have a retain cycle until you call `self.action()`. Alternatively,
2. Have either object *not* retain the other. Typically, this is done by deciding which object is the owner of the other in a parent-child relationship, and typically, `self` ends up retaining the closure strongly, while the closure references `self` weakly via `weak self`, to avoid retaining it

These rules are true *regardless* of what `self` is, and what the closure does: whether network calls, animation callbacks, etc.

With your original code, you only actually have a retain cycle if `apiClient` is a member of `self`, and holds on to the closure for the duration of the network request:

```
func performRequest() {
   apiClient.performRequest { [weak self] result in
      self?.handleResult(result)
   }
}
```

If the closure is actually dispatched elsewhere (e.g., `apiClient` does not retain the closure directly), then you don't actually need `[weak self]`, because there was never a cycle to begin with!

The rules are *exactly* the same with Swift concurrency and `Task`:

1. The closure you pass into a `Task` to initialize it with retains the objects it references by default (unless you use `[weak ...]`)
2. `Task` holds on to the closure for the duration of the task (i.e., while it's executing)
3. You will have a retain cycle if `self` holds on to the `Task` for the duration of the execution

In the case of `function2()`, the `Task` is spun up and dispatched asynchronously, but `self` *does not hold on* to the resulting `Task` object, which means that there's no need for `[weak self]`. If instead, `function2()` stored the created `Task`, *then* you would have a potential retain cycle which you'd need to break up:

```
class AsyncClass {
    var runningTask: Task?

    func function4() {
        // We retain `runningTask` by default.
        runningTask = Task {
            // Oops, the closure retains `self`!
            self.printSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to hold on to the task (e.g. so you can [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3851218-cancel) it), you'll want to avoid having the task retain `self` back (`Task { [weak self] ... }`).

Comment: Great answer.  John Sundell also has a *lot* of posts on the new swift concurrency which go into depth and provide many examples, including many of the edge cases.

Comment: So imagine `apiClient` contains a reference to a `URLSession`, and the `URLSession` performs the network request, and the completion you see in my example is called from the completion of that network request (e.g. `dataTaskWithUrl` or something).

Presumably the `URLSession` retains the closure for the duration of the request?

Comment: @MattBeaney If `apiClient` has a strong reference to the `URLSession` you’re using, then yes, you’ll have a retain cycle for the duration of the request. However, as soon as the request is done, `URLSession` should dispose of the closure (there’s no reason to hold on to it forever), so the cycle should break. It’s marginally safer to use `[weak self]` in that case, but shouldn’t be _necessary_. (This is like the `action` example in my answer.)

Comment: @Rob Ah, good call! Will update.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the feedback again — took it out to avoid confusing thins unnecessarily.

Comment: Reference cycles are certainly the most obvious (and important) reason to use weak self-references, but I'd argue that network requests are a close second. If the user dismisses a controller while a request is outstanding, a strong reference will prevent the controller from being released. The response handler may then attempt to perform an action on the controller's view, which is no longer in the hierarchy.